# Notice: Array to string conversion when calling soapV2 with complexfilter

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I want to get the orderList by using soap, the code like the following

```
<?php

    $cs = getSesstion();

    $fromDate = date('Y-m-d'. ' 00:00:00', strtotime('-1 days'));
    $todayDate = date('Y-m-d'. ' 00:00:00');
    $params = array('complex_filter'=>  
        array('key'=>'created_at','value'=>array('key' =>'gteq','value' => $fromDate)),
        array('key'=>'created_at','value'=>array('key' =>'lteq','value' => $todayDate)),
    );

    $result = $cs['client']->__call('salesOrderList',$params);

    //var_dump($result);

    function getSesstion() {

        //$client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
        $client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

        $username = 'test';
        $apikey= 'Abcd1234';            

        $session = $client->login($username, $apikey);
        $cs = array();
        $cs['client'] = $client;
        $cs['session'] = $session;
        return $cs;

    }
?>
```

The error message is

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\soap\call_getorder.php on line 13

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [5] Session expired. Try to relogin. in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\soap\call_getorder.php:13 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\soap\call_getorder.php(13): SoapClient->__call('salesOrderList', Array) #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\soap\call_getorder.php on line 13
```

Anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of incorrect format in `$params`. You forgot to use an array to embed the whole `$param`. So on line 1., modify to the follows:

```
$result = $cs['client']->__call('salesOrderList',array($params));
```

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html